# Why were Norwegian crews flying for Bomber Command paid more than other RAF crews?

Tags: world-war-two

In his book [*Bomber Command*](https://www.maxhastings.com/products/bomber-command/), Max Hastings mentions offhandedly that

> All the Norwegians were immensely rich by RAF standards because they received flying pay of eight shillings per hour operational in addition to their £28 a month salary.

Why was this so? Why were Norwegian bomber crews paid more than other RAF bomber crews? Was this true of other non-UK (or non-Commonwealth) Allied crews?

Comment: Perhaps they got extra pay from the Norwegian government-in-exile?

Comment: @TomasBy I'd guess something like that (though one might expect that to have been then subtracted from their £28 a month salary).

Comment: Does it say other RAF pilots weren't given the same flying pay?

Comment: @Shwern What do you mean?

Comment: @TomasBy that's my guess as well, I know the Dutch crews in the Pacific were under contract with the Dutch government and paid by them but under command of the US. A similar situation may have existed in the UK with Norwegians

Answer (score 5):

During operations of [Royal Norwegian Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Norwegian_Air_Force) from Britain,

> Both planes and running costs were financed by the exiled Norwegian government.

This probably explains the difference in pay.

A good question is where the money came from - [one source is](https://www.arkivverket.no/en/using-the-archives/world-war-ii/norway-in-exile):

> the big Norwegian merchant fleet outside German-controlled areas

Comment: [Before they discovered all that oil!](https://www.nbim.no) Even then they took better care of their citizens.

Comment: Yes, they brought their old gold with them.

Comment: Well, military pilots are not exactly commoners...

Comment: We’ll with life expectancies in weeks —

Comment: The main income for the norvegian government-in-exile were services ie a cut of the allieds/and other private enterprises employ of norvegian merchant ships and their crews.

Which together with running of electricity intensive industrial processes (fertilizers/aluminium etc) was the main norvegian export products until the oil industry.